# modify a Kotlin class

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin

I'd like to write a plugin for Intellij IDEA that should modify a Java and Kotlin code.

I use the method

```
PsiClass.getMethods()
```

in order to get all methods of Java and Kotlin classes. So far so good, so then I use methods like

```
PsiClass.add(), PsiClass.addAfter(), PsiClass.addBefore()
```

that all work fine once they are called on Java files, but start to throw an exception

```
IncorrectOperationException
```

once I called them on a Kotlin class.

I'd appreciate any hint on how I can modify Kotlin and Java classes (preferably using the same approach).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you search for a Kotlin class via the `JavaPsiFacade`, it returns the light class which is a shallow representation that is just based on the information in the class file. In order to add PSI elements, you have to call `navigationElement` on it. Then, IJ will parse the source and build a full PSI tree that can be modified.

However, if the class is a Kotlin class, `navigationElement` will return a `KtClass` which is not derived from `PsiClass`. You will have to use the facilities in the Kotlin hierarchy to modify it. Method instances in Kotlin are also not instances of `PsiMethod`, but instances of `KtMethod`.

For analyzing Java and Kotlin sources in a common fashion there is a different syntax tree called "UAST", but for modifications you need a language-specific approach.

Comment: Your suggestions seem to work. Thank you! Could you advice some resource where I could find out more on the topic? I have not found such information on a tutorial http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html of the JetBrain site.

Comment: I think you will have to look at the source code of IJ and Kotlin.